# Extending Controllers and passing variables

Tags: php, controller, backend

I have a Backend Controller and other controllers that extend the Backend Controller and I'm trying to figure out how to set a variable in the Backend Controller and use it in the controllers that extend it.

If I set a variable which is a configuration value in the backend controller how can the sub controllers access it.

EDIT:

http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2010/02/CodeIgniter-Base-Classes-Keeping-it-DRY

I am using the phil sturgeon base classes keeping it dry approach with my application and the controllers are shown below and when I load my login controller I get a 500 error but if I load the CI controller welcome that is included with the application it loads just fine.

Why am I getting the 500 error when the login controller is accessed.

```
<?php 

if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();  
    }

    public function index()
    {   

    }
}

<?php 

if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Backend_Controller extends MY_Controller 
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();  
    }

    public function index()
    {   

    }
}

<?php 

if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends Backend_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();  
    }

    public function index()
    {   

    }
}
```

Comment: Well, thats quite vague...

Comment: Please elaborate your question; it is hard to help you with that little detail.

Comment: This is not a question but an invitation to guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your backend controller (the parent) has an instance variable with a visibility of public or protected, then the controllers that extend the backend controller will be able to access those variables using the `$this` keyword.

Example:

```
<?php
class ParentController {
    protected $foo = "bar";
}

class ChildController extends ParentController {
    public function indexAction() {
        echo $this->foo;
    }
}
```

Comment: For some reason when I load apply this logic I just get a white screen and no errors.

Comment: Sounds like you're getting errors but haven't configured PHP to display errors. You can enable the display of error in your PHP ini file:

    display_errors On
    error_reporting E_ALL|E_STRICT

Comment: I made an edit that explains more of the issue.

Comment: Okay I figured out that I forgot to add the frontend and backend controllers to the core folder however in the backend controller i have the protected $cms_template = $this->config->item('default_cms_template'); that presents the 500 error however if I do $cms_template = 'mytemplate'; then it works any idea how I can fix this?